# AmCharts Value axis not starting at Zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I have a AmCharts serial chart with some columns representing numeric values. Depending on those values, sometimes one of the axes "unsticks" from the ground,  [making a weird effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccSeL.png). I have unsuccessfully tried to set the property valueAxis.minimum to zero.

Is there a way to force a valueAxis to start from zero?

```
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "synchronizeGrid": true,
        "valueAxes": 
            [{
                "minimum": 0,
                // ...
            }]
        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes AmCharts doesn't respect the [`minimum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) you set, depending on your data and other factors. You can try to force it by setting [`strictMinMax`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#strictMinMax) to true for each valueAxis where you want your `minimum` enforced (of course, you have to make sure you're setting `minimum` in each value axis).

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    //"synchronizeGrid": true,
    "valueAxes": 
        [{
            "minimum": 0,
            "strictMinMax": true,
            // ...
        },
         //repeat if you have multiple value axes that need to start from 0
        ]
    // ...
});
```

Note that if you're using the `synchronizeGrid` feature mentioned at the bottom of [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/), then you have to disable it or else it won't respect your min/max values at all.

Comment: for amCharts v4+, please use var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;